# How To Skip RSS Feeds Missing Certain Attributes

Tags: python, django, rss, apscheduler

I have a list of RSS feeds that i want to parse in my Django Application. Some contain all my desired attributes, others don't have some of the attributes. The ones that miss my desired attributes keep crashing my program. I keep getting such errors.

```
raise AttributeError("object has no attribute '%s'" % key)
AttributeError: object has no attribute 'summary'
```

My model

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Post Title', null=False)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Post Link', null=False)
    summary = models.TextField(verbose_name='Post Summary', null=False)
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=500, null=False, verbose_name='Post Image URL', default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=500, null=False)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Date Published', null=False)
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Guid Code', null=True)
    feed_title = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Feed Channel Title', null=False)
    feed_description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Feed Channel Description', null=False)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Date Created', null=False)
    last_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Last Modified', null=False)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Source', null=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Category', null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} - {self.feed_title}" 

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
```

My RSS save function

```
if not Posts.objects.filter(slug=post_slug).exists():
            try:
                post = Posts.objects.get(slug=post_slug)

            except Posts.DoesNotExist:
                post = Posts(
                    title = post_title,
                    link = post_link,
                    summary = post_summary,
                    image_url = image_link,
                    slug = post_slug,
                    pub_date = date_published,
                    guid = item.guid,
                    feed_title = channel_feed_title,
                    feed_description = channel_feed_desc,
                    source_id = selected_source_id,
                    category_id = selected_category_id
                )
                post.save()

                for i in range(len(article_list)):
                    post_tags = post.tags.add(article_list[i])
```

Some help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To skip a content based on missing value, you can check if that value is empty before calling your modal for creation:

```
if summary is not None and summary != '':
    
    post, created = Posts.objects.get_or_create(
                          title=post_title,
                          link=post_link,
                          summary=post_summary,
                          image_url=image_link,
                          slug=post_slug,
                          pub_date=date_published,
                          guid=item.guid,
                          feed_title=channel_feed_title,
                          feed_description=channel_feed_desc,
                          source_id=selected_source_id,
                          category_id=selected_category_id
                          )

    for article in article_list:
        post.tags.add(article)
else:
    pass   # skips and moves forward.
```

Comment: i don't want to give empty attributes a default or empty object, I want to skip it completely. Like in my case, the summary is an important part of my RSS application. So giving it a default value wont work coz every post has a different summary depending on the story. So placing a default value just wont work in my use case. Also leaving it empty wont work coz having a RSS title with no summary wont be of much help. So for me, skipping such posts completely is the way to go.

Comment: I don't understand. So you are saying if summary or title is empty, you don't want to create the `Posts` object at all?

Comment: Yes, all my attributes in my model have null=False, meaning i don't want any column to have empty cells. So in cases an RSS feed has an attribute like in this `summary` as empty, i want the Post object to be skipped and not saved in the database. My current save function doesn't skip such, thus raising errors. I hope i am now clear.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please assist in placing it in the save function above? I would really appreciate that.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You don't need to do if statement as you were doing try/catch for the same thing, it's redundant as both parts do the same job. Then instead of using try/catch, you can use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) function which either fetches the model entry with given parameters, or creates a new one.